# Android Menu just 2 items in actionbar

Tags: java, android, menu

I want to display menu items in the actionbar of my app. The problem is: I have an item "Login" and an item "Save username?" (<-- is checkable). I want the "Login" display as it is in the actionbar and the "Save username?" in a "..." 
How is this possible? I see it like in Whatsapp, but I don't know how to get this "..." and store items in it

Comment: you can use this link http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: is there no other method? :/ I read that this dots come into beeing if there is no more space, but for me there are no dots, even if I create 4 items :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your phone has a hardware menu button, you won't be able to able to see the vertical ellipsis. Instead, press the menu button and the remaining action bar items should show up.